# how do I add a preloader to opencart with the Journal theme

Tags: opencart

I am working on a website on Opencart with the journal theme and i'm trying to add a preloader to it do you know what files to edit to insert it?
i tried to look for it into the /catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your code to
catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/common/header.twig

but you should make your modification as ocmod file and upload it to the system throuth modification part in the admin panel.

You may have a look at this article about ocmod in opencart3:
https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-3-ocmod-coding-tutorial/

Comment: thanks i didn't edit that file but it gave me the right inicatios i edited the catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/common/home.twig file and added the preloader animation thanks for the answer